# How do I make this nav bar logo responsive?

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile

How do I make the nav bar logo resize properly and how do I fix the hamburger menu? I have tried to apply a media query to the nav bar logo and this does not seem to work...how to I make this nav bar logo responsive? It shrinks when I look at it on mobile. Also how do I fix the javascript void issue and fix the hamburger menu? Thanks in advance.
code:

```js
var x = document.getElementById("myTopnav");
if (x.className === "topnav") {
  x.className += " responsive_nav";
} else {
  x.className = "topnav";
}
```

```css
  width: 20%;
height: 20%;
align-self: flex-start;
padding-top: 5px;

}
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  #home {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  
  .topnav a {
    display: none;
  }
  
  .topnav a.icon {
    float: right;
    display: block;
  }
  
  .topnav.responsive_nav {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  .topnav.responsive_nav a.icon {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 15px;
  }
  
  .topnav.responsive_nav a:not(:first-child) {
    float: none;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
    color: white !important;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    padding: 10px 0 !important;
    background-color: #0F0F0F;
    transition: 0.5s;
    border: 3px solid #1F1F1F;
  }
  
  .topnav.responsive_nav a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(27, 29, 32, 0.15);
  }
  
  .lang {
    align-self: flex-start;
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
nav {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 0.2vw;
  /*updated*/
  
  font-family: calibri;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0.3vw 2vw;
  /*updated*/
  
  background-color: #F4F7FF;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  z-index: 10;
}
nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #010b0a
}

/*nav ul{ list-style-type: none; }*/
nav div a {
  float: left;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
nav div a:hover {
  background-color: #0ee4cc;
  /*added*/
}
nav div a:hover {
  color: #F4F7FF;
  /*added*/
}
@media(max-width:900px) {
  .toggle span {
    display: block;
    width: 25px;
    height: 3px;
    background-color: black;
    margin: 6px 0;
  }
  
  .toggle:before {
    font-family: calibri;
    line-height: 0px;
    margin-left: -30px;
  }
  /*nav ul{ position:absolute; width: 100%; height:auto; box-sizing:border-box; background-color:#0F0F0F; top: 50px; left: 0; transition: 0.5s; overflow: hidden; display: none !important; border:3px solid #1F1F1F; padding:0px; margin:0px; } */
  /*nav ul li a{ border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.10) ; color:#ffffff !important; width: 100%; height: 50px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; }*/
  
  .active-menu {
    display: block !important;
  }
  /*nav ul li a:hover{ background-color:rgba(27,29,32,0.15); }*/
  
  @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    #home {
      margin-top: 100px;
    }
    .topnav a {
      display: none;
    }
    .topnav a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
    }
    .topnav.responsive_nav {
      position: relative;
    }
    .topnav.responsive_nav a.icon {
      position: absolute;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      left: 15px;
    }
    .topnav.responsive_nav a:not(:first-child) {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: center;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.10);
      color: white !important;
      margin: 10px 0 0 0;
      padding: 10px 0 !important;
      background-color: #0F0F0F;
      transition: 0.5s;
      border: 3px solid #1F1F1F;
    }
    .topnav.responsive_nav a:hover {
      background-color: rgba(27, 29, 32, 0.15);
    }
    .lang {
      align-self: flex-start;
      padding-top: 10px;
    }
  }
  
  @media(max-width:900px) {
    .toggle span {
      display: block;
      width: 25px;
      height: 3px;
      background-color: black;
      margin: 6px 0;
    }
    .toggle:before {
      font-family: calibri;
      line-height: 0px;
      margin-left: -30px;
    }
    /*nav ul{ position:absolute; width: 100%; height:auto; box-sizing:border-box; background-color:#0F0F0F; top: 50px; left: 0; transition: 0.5s; overflow: hidden; display: none !important; border:3px solid #1F1F1F; padding:0px; margin:0px; } */
    /*nav ul li a{ border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255,255,255,0.10) ; color:#ffffff !important; width: 100%; height: 50px; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; margin: 0px !important; padding: 0px !important; }*/
    .active-menu {
      display: block !important;
    }
    /*nav ul li a:hover{ background-color:rgba(27,29,32,0.15); }*/
    .p-container {
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: auto;
      grid-gap: 10px;
      height: auto;
    }
    .c-b-heading {
      font-size: 1.4rem;
      text-align: center;
    }
    #contact-form {
      padding: 20px;
      height: auto;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    #contact-form form {
      flex-direction: column;
      height: auto;
      padding: 20px;
      width: 90% !important;
    }
    .contact-left,
    .contact-right {
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
    }
    .f-name,
    .f-email {
      width: 100%;
    }
    .f-name input,
    .f-email input {
      width: 100%;
      border: none;
      background-color: #262626 !important;
      padding: 10px;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      height: 40px;
    }
    textarea {
      background-color: #262626 !important;
      margin: 10px 0px;
      padding: 10px;
      height: 200px !important;
      width: 100% !important;
    }
    .message {
      margin: 0px;
    }
    #contact-form form h1 {
      margin: 5px 0px;
    }
  }
```

```html
<nav>
  <img src="logo.png" alt="Nature" class="responsive">
  <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="toggleFunction()">
      <div class="toggle"><span></span><span></span><span></span></div>
    </a>
    <a href="#main" id="home">home</a>
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#services">Services</a>
    <a href="#portfolio">Projects</a><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="toggleFunction()">
  </div>
  <!--language--><a class="lang">En</a>
</nav>
```

Comment: when I look on mobile (320 x 667) it shrinks and is almost unreadable.

Comment: It's not really clear what you're asking - can you specify what you are expecting to see/happen and what you are seeing/is happening instead? Your code is also not complete, maybe try making a fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/](https://jsfiddle.net/) or pen [https://codepen.io/](https://codepen.io/) instead of dropping the whole shebang in here.